# Allow any digit in a string other than 9 and 16 digits

Tags: java, regex

```
^(?![\\s\\S]*(\\d{16})|[\\s\\S]*(\\d{9}))[\\s\\S]*
```

The above regex does not allow a number greater than 10 digits in the string.
Example, if user enters test 1234567891. The text is a valid text. We should allow user to enter this text.
The user should only not enter a 9 digit number or a 16 digit number. 
Example, test 123456789 should be invalid. How to modify the regex.

Comment: This regex actually is defective (unbalanced parentheses), and even if you balanced them, it still wouldn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Andremoniy the negative lookahead is not closed

Comment: @fge, ups, I just misread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a regex for this kind of check. Java has `.length()` on strings:

```
private static final Pattern DIGITS = "\\d+";

public boolean inputOK(String input)
{
    Matcher m = DIGITS.matcher(input);

    int len;

    while (m.find()) {
        len = m.group().length();
        if (len == 9 || len == 16)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Is this requirement best served by a regexp ? I think it would be *much* more readable to check the string length, and if you have a number.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

and see [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html).

Comment: May be, but I think this person has homework about regular expressions.

Comment: @Andremoniy You may be right, but if so I think it is an unfortunate choice of problem. A big part of learning programming languages and constructs is learning to make good choices of which tool to use for a given problem. Asking someone to work out how to use a screwdriver to drive a nail is not a good way of teaching correct application of screwdrivers and hammers.